# New self-built computer - dual-boot Win10/Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

Having issues setting up dual-boot.
New machine - ASUS Z170 Deluxe

1. Ubuntu installer doesn't recognize that Windows already is there.
2. Chose to "do something else"

2.1 - Created /, swap and /usr partitions

2.2 - For boot location, chose the win-created EFI partition

3 Installed Ubuntu with no apparent issues

3.1 - After installation, boots direct to Windows - it will boot Ubuntu and (apparently) run fine if I go to BIOS and boot from the main partition.

4. After install, from Ubuntu Terminal, a command I found on a website indicates Ubuntu installed in legacy mode vs EFI mode.

Since this is a new machine, I'm willing to entirely scrub everything and start over if there's something I could have done better with the Windows install.

I have not tried to do any elaborate fixes yet. As I am browsing for solutions, I seem to find many different solutions that are possibly conflicting.

Comment: Is Windows installed in legacy or UEFI mode?  You don't mean you assigned /boot to the EFI partition do you?  If you left the BIOS/UEFI settings in CSM mode, you are letting the machine decide which mode, which might not be the mode you want.

Comment: I didn't explicitly assign /boot to the EFI partition - but in the dialog box I chose the partition Windows created labeled EFI (maybe that's the same thing) in the drop-down.  I assumed GRUB would replace the Windows boot manager located there.  Haven't checked (yet) if Windows is installed in UEFI or legacy mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While UEFI provides some nice features like Secure Boot, overall it's just a pain to deal with.

Since you're willing to start over, here's what I suggest:

1. Go into the BIOS, and **>>disable UEFI<<**, and enable legacy boot.
2. Install Windows*, formatting the entire disk. Make sure it is installed in legacy MBR mode. To do so, open Disk Management and verify that there is only a System Reserved NTFS partition in front of your main Windows partition.
3. Use Disk Management to shrink your partition, creating unallocated space for Ubuntu.
4. While still in Windows, **disable** hibernation and Fast Boot
5. Use the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option in Ubuntu's installer wizard. It will automatically install to the unallocated space you created earlier.
6. Reboot and verify you are met with GRUB

*In order to make sure the Windows installer is forced to boot into legacy mode:

> BIOS: To prevent Windows Setup or Windows PE from booting in UEFI
>   mode, remove the efi folder on the root of the media. (Excerpt from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode).)

Enjoy not having the hassle of UEFI!

Comment: I'll give that a try.  Just a couple questions:
1) after disabling UEFI in BIOS, is there anything during Win10 install I need to do to force legacy mode?
2) Why use the whole partition and shrink later?  I didn't think Windows could to that - I thought only PartEd or another third-party program could.

Comment: @BayPort1964 - I've edited my answer to address your first question. As to the second, feel free to partition it during install. And yes, you can shrink the Windows partition from inside Windows. I've done it myself.

Comment: After a few mishaps, I finally got it all working as expected!

Comment: (and the enter key submits the post)...
Thanks for the help! - I learned that Ubuntu doesn't like the ASmedia ATA ports.  I used them because the SATA express ports on the MOBO share bandwith with the M.2 drive.  Unfortunately, I made that change at the same time I was dealing with the Ubuntu dual-boot issues - off on a tangent.
I got that resolved, then installed Ubuntu "alongside" Windows, but the installer decided to put Ubuntu on the HDD instead of the SDD.
So I tried "do something else", but the installer defaults to nvme0 for the boot location (fatal error).

Comment: The correct boot location is something like "nvme0p1".   So I unplugged the HDD and optical, chose the right partition, and finally got it working right.

Comment: Oh... another hitch - can't remember where in this saga it occurred, but at one point the Win10 entry in GRUB was pointing to GRUB (likely a bad choice on boot location in setup).

Comment: @BayPort1964 - So are you completely UEFI free?

Comment: I think so.  BIOS still shows "secure boot" enabled, but set to "other OS".  But I don't see a Windows partition labeled EFI any more.

Comment: **Good**. You are now rid of the ulgy and needlessly complicated boot process!

Answer (score 0):

Install the boot-loader in an external disk such as a flash drive. W10 presents problems with dual booting that doesn't seem to be solved anytime soon. This complication is worth it for me.

Comment: I took your advice and used a flash drive.  This came in handy as I had issues with Ubuntu not liking the fact that my HDD & Optical were plugged in to an ASmedia ATA port .  Also a good deal faster.  I didn't initially want to mess with the extra steps/downloads to make a bootable USB, but it was worth it.

Comment: Glad to hear that :D Happy Llamas to you! @BayPort1964